# Omniture Video Milestones: How do change quarterly reporting to something friendlier?

Tags: video, adobe-analytics

I'm able to track quarterly milestones of brightcove video, but its returning values such as these:

```
1:M:0-25
```

and so.

How do I change that so its reporting something friendlier to view such as:

```
25% complete
```

I'm using javascript to make the reporting in the media module.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 3 options, which I will list from easiest to hardest:

1) Create a SAINT classification for your variable. Have a column with the friendlier name and look at that column instead of the raw value. Since it's only like 4 values, you can set this up pretty quickly. There may be some gotchas on exactly what is available in the reports from the classification vs. the raw key, so this may not be good enough to you. But IMO it's worth checking it out first since it doesn't involve making changes to the code.

2) Put some logic in your `s_doPlugins` function to check if your segment eVar is set and what the value is and change it to the value you want. A js object "lookup table" or just a simple `switch` will do. If I had to go the js route, I'd probably choose this option over option 3, despite my notes, simply because it's less code to mess around with.

3) There is a way to tap into the milestone events with a callback function (`Media.monitor`  look at the media docs). Basically you would add the callback function to your js file and check for the MILESTONE event and have a `switch` to check "x%" value to write a different value for your eVar. Kinda same principle as #2 but wrapped in the built-in media event handler. Adobe doesn't provide an official way to do it, but if you went to ClientCare and asked, this is likely what they'd officially tell you to do.  It's not that there's anything wrong with option #2; it's just that this is more of a "keep similar code together" option.